# Labels and commands are not recognized after chcp

Tags: batch-file

I have a piece of code here:

```
@echo off
set /p "filePath=Enter file path>"
if exist "%filePath%" set /p string=< %filePath%
>nul chcp 950

echo testString
:Loop
```

When executed, it outputs `cho is not recongnized...` and `Loop is not recognized as...`. The first character of the some(not all!) commands are trimmed. Also, I have tried removing the `chcp` and the script works fine, but I needed it. Please assist me to find out the reason behind this and solutions. Thanks.

Here's some system specifications:

- Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit
- cmd.exe, New console features enabled

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem with the code you posted. Please double-check that your script is saved with ANSI encoding.

Comment: My script is saved as Big5 as indicated by notepad++.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't reproduce this issue, but I noticed that codepage 950 is not listed as supported on the chcp command reference page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp).

Perhaps you could use code page 936 which is for simplified Chinese, instead of 950.

[image: List of supported code pages]

Comment: [Relevant](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2006/03/06/544251.html). It seems you _can_ use chcp 950, but it has to be the default system OEM code page.

Comment: No wonder it doesn't work as expected. My default codepage is 437. When I'm available, I'll try changing the default codepage and see if it works. I'll get you updated.

Comment: I have changed my default codepage to 950, and I tested the same script and no random errors occurred.